# AngularUI modal dialog - calling dialog's controller function on "rendered" event

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to call dialog's controller function on $modal.rendered event, is this doable without polluting $scope?

Here is a sample Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HzFe65RY3hNme8QuUWaJ?p=preview

So, in promise:

```
modalDialog.rendered.then(function () {
    demo.message = 'Dialog opened';
});
```

I would like to call onLoaded function from modalController controller.

Thank you, best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a factory/service to share data & functions across controllers;

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('demoController',['$modal', 'modalService', function($modal, service) {
  var demo = this;

  demo.message = 'It works!'

  demo.modal = function() {
    var modalDialog = $modal.open({
      controller: 'modalController',
      controllerAs: 'modal',
      templateUrl: 'modal.html'
    });

    modalDialog.rendered.then(function () {
      demo.message = 'Dialog opened';
      service.onLoaded();
    });
  };
}])
.controller('modalController', ['$modalInstance', 'modalService', function($modalInstance, service) {
  var modal = this;
  service.modalText = 'Modal Text';
  modal.shared = service;

  modal.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
  }

}])
.factory('modalService', function() {
  var service = {
    modalText: 'Modal text',
    onLoaded: onLoaded
  };
  return service;
  function onLoaded() {
    service.modalText = 'Modal loaded';
  }
})
```

And the following update to the html;

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <pre>{{ modal.shared.modalText }}</pre>
</div>
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q704IjkHSAYwuCfLuYnU?p=preview

Comment: I think that this won't work in the same way as the "rendered" event. "Rendered" is resolved when a modal dialog is rendered and DOM is ready. Calling modal.onLoaded() directly will won't wait for DOM.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot move onLoaded out of modalController.

Comment: are you able to add code to onLoaded in modalController?

Comment: No, I cannot add code to onLoaded in modalController